# Nested store actions not synchronized

Tags: angular, asynchronous, redux, observable, ngrx

I'm using NgRx to handle my app state.

I have a mat-slider component to change time on my app.

When user change slider value a list of actual trips get updated on the app state, then shown on a tube map SVG component.

The trips progression is calculated depending on the selected time on slider and the arrival and departure time.

I'm able to do that.

My problem is when I update the selected time. the list of actual trips is not updated quickly on the store so the selected time is get applied on old trips subscribed values , then on new trips values when they get updated on the store.

I think it's an asynchronous problem due to my bad observables implementing, but I can find how to do better.

Here's my implementation

```
selectedDate$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectDateTimeSelect));
this.selectedDate$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(elm => {
          this.selectedTime = elm.timeSelect; // get actual Time selected
          this.store.dispatch(new GetSchedulesByTime(elm.timeSelect.toString()));
          return this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulings)); // return new scheduling data ( may be here the update still not happened ? )
        })
      )
      .subscribe((schedules: ISchedule[]) => { // subscribe to that new data
     ..... treatment....
     })
```

Here's the reducer

```
case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByTime: {
  let time = action.payload;
  return { ...state, actualTrips: [...(state.schedulings[time] || [])] };
}
```

Then the selector

```
export const selectSchedulings = createSelector(
  schedulings,
  (state: ISchedulesState) => state.actualTrips
);
```

I can't provide a working demo because reproduction is not simple.
I think I have provided many elements.

How can I be sure that actual trips are updated before proceeding to treatment ?

**Update**
I'm trying to chain actions inside an effect

```
$updateActualTrips = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(ESelectDateTimeActionTypes.SetSelectDateTime),
    switchMap(action => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetNextSchedulesByTime, payload: action.payload }))
  )
);
```

But I get this error

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest (but not too pretty) solution would be to

```
return this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulings), skip(1));
```

A prettier solution would be to update `schedulings` in your store via reducer whenever `selectedDate` gets changed. This way you don't need to send a separate action for that

Comment: So I should use an effect for that and fire a `getSchedulings` ( I should better call it `setSchedulingsbyTime` )

Comment: you can change two things in the reducer simultaneously: both update `selectedDate` and recalculate `schedulingsbyTime` trigerred by same action of changing `selectedDate`. Depends on your use-case, of course, but seems viable

Comment: I updated my question by trying to do it with effects firstly